# THROW or RAISERROR for specific non-user defined error codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, throw, raiserror

I'm trying to test some code that traps a specific error code in SQL server.  The error code is 7886.

When I try to `THROW`, I get:

```
Error number 7886 in the THROW statement is outside the valid range. Specify an error number in the valid range of 50000 to 2147483647.
```

When I try to `RAISERROR`, I get:

```
Error number 7886 is invalid. The number must be from 13000 through 2147483647 and it cannot be 50000.
```

**Is there any way to raise an arbitrary error like this without actually setting up the situation to cause the error in the first place?**

Comment: No, you cannot raise system errors yourself in T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments of the original question, this is impossible to do in SQL server.

:(